# Restarting Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an application that will only be run on a local network and  am looking for the best way to restart my server from within the application itself. For the time being this is only running on Windows using WEBrick.

Comment: Why do you need to restart your server from your app?

Comment: Basically just to make it as user friendly as possible while updating the app. Meaning that if I push an update the user can just click a button to update and restart without any hassle.

Comment: This is what capistrano is for. Create a post-deploy cap task that restarts the server when the update is done.

Comment: Thanks Srdjan, I'll take a look at capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Capistrano as others have suggested, it's fantastic :)

```
$ cap deploy
```

That's all you have to do.  It'll grab the latest source from your git/SVN repo (lots more supported ofc), deploy, and restart your app server.